# How to Check intersection between two images on a specific location?

Tags: java, android, intersection

How can I check intersection between two images on a specific location in the second image.

For example:

There's Image 1 and Image 2.

I want to know if Image 1 intersects with Image 2 IN a specific location.

Here's the image for example :

[image]

I want to check if Image 1 intersects with the white part in this object.

How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this for a game or something?

Comment: Thanks for replying and yes , it's for a game

Comment: This is usually handled using a tile map and not an image, for example, you create a tile map with a layer which represents what the player see(i.e. the image that you posted) and another layer above the last one which is not visible where you define which tile is collisionable or not, doing that you can identify where you should collide(red line) and where not (white space).